# Rich snippets and javascript generated markup

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine, microformats

Microformat rich snippets markup generated with javascript are indexed by the search engines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, yes, unless you block Google from accessing the Javascript file that generates the markup from `robots.txt`.

Comment: http://www.greenlaneseo.com/blog/2010/02/google-and-javascript/

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518

Comment: unrelated, but part of the power of microformats is tied to the markup; google may index your content, but most page parsers/scrapers won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tests and research the answer is: No as of current day :(

Neither in the form of javascript generated html or via an iframe tag.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I am thinking of using the hidden <meta itemprop="..." content="...">...</meta> format.

Comment: @Kirk: Hi, I didn't find a way to do that :( Seems that the search engines right now aren't capable to fully scrap generated content.